# Why 'a like a' returns false in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a string in MySQL, when I select using like, it returns nothing.
After some investigation, I found a strange behavior of MySQL.

```
select a,a=a,a like a from (
  select '123' as a union all
  select '\\"'
)x
```

result:

| a | a=a | a like a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 |
| \" | 1 | 0 |

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/313965

I think `a like a` should always return 1 (expect for `a=null`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of a `LIKE` expression in MySQL, backslash reserves a special meaning which is to escape the character which follows it.  This is needed, for example, if we want to include a literal underscore in a `LIKE` expression.

Appreciate that the following is true:

```sql
'"' LIKE '\"'
```

This is true because the backslash in the `LIKE` expression is literal and is used to escape the double quote.  The following two are identical:

```sql
'"' LIKE '\\"'
'"' LIKE '"'
```

Here the double backslash in what follows `LIKE` is interpreted as double escaping the double quote.

The correct version of what you were trying to do is:

```sql
'\\"' LIKE '\\\\"'
```

Here the LHS is a literal backslash followed by double quote.  The RHS needs *four* backslashes for a literal backslash.

Comment: +1. So one "corrected" version of `a LIKE a` would be `a LIKE REPLACE(a, '\\', '\\\\')`. (Alternatively, the documentation for LIKE implies that we can write `a LIKE a ESCAPE ''` -- "The escape sequence should be [...] empty to specify that no escape character is used" \[[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)\] -- but when I tried it on SQL Fiddle, the `ESCAPE ''` seemed to have no effect, so, dunno.)